# base de datos sql y php: Llenar una columna a partir de otra

Tags: php, sql

tengo una duda. Quería preguntar si se puede llenar una columna a partir de otra columna, en una tabla, en la cual solo un campo cambiaría (seria el año, las claves de esta tabla son un id y un año) bueno eso no me complica tanto.

Lo que quiero saber es si puedo hacer para TODAS las columnas que tengan un id único, o sea quiero que todas las columnas se actualicen con un campo cambiado, que seria el siguiente año (ya dije que el año también es clave).

En este caso, la actualización es crear otra columna con un campo cambiado(el año). ¿Puedo hacer eso pero para que todas las columnas se "actualicen" de una? o lo tengo que hacer uno x uno?

Gracias

Comment: Danos la estructura de las tablas, parece un problema sencillo de resolver.

Comment: Mas o menos es: Tabla Colegio (ID PK, AÑO PK/FK, NOMBRE, CIUDAD,DIRECTOR,FONO) Cada año se registra una columna con el id del colegio, el año, el nombre,ciudad,etc. Esa seria la "actualización" ya que se registran todos los años ya que hay cosas que cambian. Ya lo he hecho para un colegio pero quiero hacerlo para todos de una sola vez en vez d buscar cada colegio uno x uno.

Comment: La explicación que haces me hace pensar en una violación a las reglas de normalización. Sería mejor que compartieras la estructura de las tablas con ejemplos de lo que quieres hacer. También aclarar sobre cual RDBMS estás trabajando.

Comment: yo no hice la base de datos, trabajo con lo que me pidieron. Ocupo MySQL

Answer (score -1):

No me ha quedado claro de la "actualización". Es decir, no se si quieres hacer un `update` de una columna, un `update` de una columna a partir de otra, o si quiere añadir (`insert`) filas a partir de las ya existentes. Me inclino por pensar que lo que quieres es la tercera opción.

Esto inserta nuevos registros para el año 2020, a partir de los datos de 2019

```
INSERT INTO Colegio (ID, AÑO, NOMBRE, CIUDAD, DIRECTOR, FONO)
SELECT ID, AÑO + 1, NOMBRE, CIUDAD, DIRECTOR, FONO
FROM Colegio
WHERE AÑO = 2019
```

Comment: Perdón, no es una actualización de verdad(por eso lo puse entre comillas) es un instert como usted puso. Lo que yo tenia era algo parecido pero el WHERE busca el año y el id. Lo que quiero es hacer eso x todas las tablas, ¿tendría que hacer un ciclo WHILE en sql?

Comment: ¿Todas las tablas? ¿Qué tablas? o ¿Todos los registros?. El campo id de un nombre en un año ¿debe ser distinto al siguiente año?

Comment: perdón, todos los registros, el nombre e id no derivan cambiar.

Comment: Entonces, la consulta que te he puesto en la respuesta hace la inserción para todos los registros de un año en el siguiente.

Comment: Gracias :) mes sirvio